# URL rewriting page load loops

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using [Intelligencia UrlRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/configuration) to apply URL Rewriting.

I took `page1.aspx` and used the `OnClick` event of a button and did a `Response.Redirect` to `page2.aspx`. Everything works fine if I test with these two sample pages.

Then I applied some styles and javascript to `page2.aspx`. When I click the same button on `page1.aspx` and put a break point on `page2.aspx.cs` `page_load` function, what I observed is that `page_load` function is looped for multiple times and it loops and loads all the database calls multiple times.

Applying `IsPostback` didn't help. Then I removed the CSS and JS then everything is fine.Need answer why this `page_load` function repeats multiple times.

Comment: have you set urlrewrite rules for JS and css folders?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too.  Like the others have touched on, it can be caused by relative paths inside your page.

I was rewriting:

```
domain.com/article/12345/title-here
```

To become:

```
domain.com/article.aspx?ID=12345
```

Problem was, there were 2 images with relative paths:

```
  EG. images/fb.jpg
      images/tw.jpg
```

By logging the value in Request.RawUrl.ToString(), I was able to see that the browser was requesting following images:

```
 domain.com/article/12345/images/fb.jpg

 domain.com/article/12345/images/tw.jpg
```

Although these files don't exist, the URL still satisfied the redirect rule.

Thus, rewriting the URL to:

```
domain.com/article.aspx?ID=12345
```

Which explains why my page loaded three times.  Once for the HTML, and once for each image.

Changed the image src values to an absolute path and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set rewrite rules for CSS and JS directory. Your page calling again and again because on request of css and JS files your page serve. set rewrite rules for your CSS and JS according to your directory system.

**Edit**
not sure may be work

```
<rewrite url="^(/.+(\.gif|/.+\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|\.asmx|\.axd|\.flv|\.swf)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop" />
```

Comment: All my css files are under Styles folder and all my js files are under js folders and both these folders are under main directory...so can you guide me how to write REWRITERULE in this case as iam completly new to url rewriting and completely lost at this point of REWRITERULES........tried but can't solve my issue

Comment: my application is in ASP .NET 3.5 C#

Comment: thanks Mr.Prakash that really saved my day...its working now and now i even understood the logic as how to handle........can u also advice few best links to gain URL REWRITING indepth knowledge...for a asp.net 3.5 C# application........

Answer (score 0):

Page load loops occur using the out of the box ASP.Net implementation as well. One oe the ways you can check for and reduce processing overhead is to check the httpContext object to see what the currently requested object is. If the object is not what you expect - an image, .js file, stylesheet, etc, bail out of the page processing.